# Default value for failed ES6 static imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, es6-modules

Let's say I have the following import statement:

```js
import panel from 'https:/mywebsite/admin/cPanel.js';
```

When my server receives such request from an unauthorized uzer, it responds with 403 error code, triggering an exeption on the client.

Is there any way to set `panel` to some default value, like in following example:

```js
  var panel = null;

  import('https:/mywebsite/admin/cPanel.js').then(response => { 
    panel = response;
  }).catch(err);
```

Comment: No, there's not. Why does an unauthorised user load the script in the first place? And why does your server check for authorisation on serving a simple script at all? That's what needs fixing.

Comment: The idea was that unauthorized user won't be able to access the code that builds the UI for secured routes, so I thought I may need a way let my system know that module fetch failed. Then I realized that protected route is technically a function of authentication and/or authorization, therefore - a function of an API request.

So it is ok to show the code which is used for building UI since user must successfully authenticate and/or authorize in order for response to be used for rendering something meaningful.